# how do deduct value 1 in front end?

Tags: html, jquery, express, mongoose, ejs

```
I write the code to reduce the value in backend but I also write the ajax call back response to reduce the value in front end using jquery. But the front end code is not decrease any value. When user click on delete button it remove the row and at the same time it need to deduct the 1 from total count. 
My html count :
   <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                        <span>Total Entries </span>
                        <h2 id="#entrycount" class="font-bold "><%= Count%></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
My ajax front end code: 
 $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function () {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
             let currentTrId = this.id;
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/delete",
                    data: { "taskId": this.id },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Response :", result);
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Deleted!',
                            'Your Task has been deleted.',
                            'success'
                        ).then((deleteResult) => {
                            $('#entrycount').html(parseInt($('#entrycount').html()) - 1);         
                            $("#" + currentTrId).fadeOut("normal", function () {
                                $(this).remove();   
                            });
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                console.log(document.getElementById(this.id)[0])
                console.log($(this).parent().parent()[0])
                console.log(this.id)
            }
        });
    });
```

When user click on delete button above ajax request made and in backend table row removed and rows count value decreased. response wills end to front end. I am able to delete the row in front end but not able to decrease the count value when user click on delete button. How can I achieve this?I tried different ways but no use.

Comment: why you have `#` here `id="#entrycount"`remove that and try again

Comment: small mistake consume 2 hours of time, Thank you now it is working